# C console repainting stuttering/not fluid

Tags: c, console-application, paint

I am trying to make a simple snake game on console. I am using an int matrix to store all the data (borders, snake, food to eat) at their exact location.

I use this main code for now to run the program :

```
int main()
{
    int tab[28][120];
    create(tab, 28, 120);
    paint(tab, 28, 120);
    char i = '1';
    char direction = 'R';
    while(i != 'q')
    {
        if (kbhit())
            i =getch();
        translate(tab, direction, 28, 120);
        paint(tab, 28, 120);
        Sleep(300);
    }   
}
```

The main problem being, every time I repaint the matrix, it stutters. I tried putting the `if(kbhit())` statement in a `for()` loop with another `paint()` call while taking of the `Sleep(300)` to speed up the paint process but it still stutters, just faster.

Would using threads help ? I am not good at understanding them.

here is the whole program that goes with the main for those who want to test it:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void paint(int tab[28][120], int ligneMax, int colonneMax)
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < ligneMax; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colonneMax; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", tab[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void create(int tab[28][120], int Nbligne, int Nbcolonne)
{
    int randligne = rand() % 26 + 1;
    int randcols = rand() % 118 + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Nbligne; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Nbcolonne; j++)
        {
            tab[i][j] = ' ';
            if (i == 0 || i == Nbligne - 1)
                tab[i][j] = 205;
            if (j == 0 || j == Nbcolonne - 1)
                tab[i][j] = 186;
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                tab[i][j] = 201;
            if (i == 0 && j == Nbcolonne - 1)
                tab[i][j] = 187;
            if (i == Nbligne - 1 && j == 0)
                tab[i][j] = 200;
            if (i == Nbligne - 1 && j == Nbcolonne - 1)
                tab[i][j] = 188;
            if (i == 14 && j == 60)
                tab[i][j] = 254;
            if (i == 14 && j == 59)
                tab[i][j] = 184;
            if (i == 14 && j == 58)
                tab[i][j] = 184;
            if (i == randligne && j == randcols)
                tab[i][j] = 176;
        }
    }
}

void translate(int tab[28][120], char direction, int Nbligne, int Nbcolonne)
{
    if (direction == 'R')
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Nbligne; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nbcolonne; j++)
            {
                if (tab[i][j] == 254)
                {
                    tab[i][j] = 184;
                    tab[i][j + 1] = 254;
                    goto stop;
                }
            }
        }
        stop: NULL;
    }
}
```

I am aware the translate function is complete (it only moves the head right for now), but it does matter on the present issue.

Comment: What does `translate` and `paint` do? What do you mean with "console repainting"? What is the program supposed to do? What output (if any) did you expect, what did you get? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), check e.g. [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: translate changes the position of the snake in the matrix according to the direction, and paint clears the console and outputs the whole matrix in the console. I got a stuttering re-painting (so painting once more) while I wanted a fluid one, but that was already in the question. I will add my whole programm for you to test if you want

Comment: C doesn't have console control, only input and output streams. Is `kbhit()` from `conio.h`? I'd strongly advice against using this header, it's very outdated. A good alternative for cross-platform console control is `curses`, you could use `ncurses` on \*nix systems (it even supports windows) and `pdcurses` specifically for windows.

Comment: To learn how to use `curses`, the [NCURSES programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) is a good read. I once implemented [a snake game](https://github.com/Zirias/cursedsnake/) to get familiar with `curses` myself ;)

Comment: It's the clearing-printing-clearing-printing-and so on that is the problem. The Windows console window program is pretty slow. I recommend you use [the Windows console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) to print only at the positions changed.

Comment: I will look into it then, thanks for the advice

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude's advice is fine as well, of course, but be aware you'll tie your code to windows in that case :)

Comment: well I am trying to make a windows program for now, I will stay simple and look into cross platform later ^^

Comment: @raiskader if cross-platform is planned already, use curses now. If you specifically aim for windows, use the native windows console API, so you avoid an external library dependency. In any case, forget about `conio.h` ;)

Comment: If you plan on going cross-platform sooner or later, then start with it immediately. It's going to be much less work in the long run. :)

Comment: the posted code spends WAY TOO MUCH time repainting the screen, etc.  Suggest not calling `system( "cls" );`   Rather use the ANSI escape sequences to modify the location of the cursor then output the appropriate  character to the current cursor location on the screen and update the image of the screen in the table[][]